# decoding a text file to another by changing the characters of the strings in the file to another specific characters

Tags: c++

I'm interested to take two text files using the argument vectors the first one as an input and the second as an output (empty/blank file) ,then decode the input file by changing **Words** (words- considered to contain only characters) or the letters of the word to "a" by the same number of letters,**Numbers** by changing each digit to "0", **anything else** (letters,numbers and punctuation) to "x". and copy the decoded to the output file keeping the same number of spaces and lines BETWEEN each string (word,number and mixed).

Note: The lines of the input shouldn't be limited !!

The Problem:

Frankly, i wrote something and it works partially, after reading each string and do the decoding, and copying the decoded to the output file it doesn't enter a line after finishing 
each line, so the program prints all the strings continuously decoded as wanted in the same
line.

Here is the code:

```
void read_line(ifstream &inp_f,ofstream &out_f)
{
    char c,
        str[MAX_STR_LEN],// holds the string that working on
        prev_str[MAX_STR_LEN]; // holds the previous string
    int count_spaces=-1,
        count_entered=0, // how many chars are in the array including '\0'
        counter[CNTR_LEN];// holds the number of each type of string in the line
    bool read=false,copy=false;

    while(!inp_f.eof())
    {
        c=inp_f.get();

        if(!isspace(c) && c!='\n')
        {
            str[count_entered]=c;
            count_entered++;
            read=true;// only if something has been read except spaces in the line
            copy=true;// used to give the command to copy the char to the string array
        }
        else if(isspace(c) || c=='\n')// when reading a space or one line
        {
            count_spaces++;

            str[count_entered]='\0';

            if(copy && strcmp(prev_str,str)!=0)
            {
                strcpy(prev_str,str);
                decode(counter,str);// Decoding the string considering it's type
                copy_str(count_spaces,str,counter,out_f); // when all the string has been read,copy it to the output file
                count_entered=0;
                count_spaces=0;
                copy=false;
            }
            ///////////////// can't take it to enter here /////////////////////////
            else if((!copy || !read) && c=='\n') // when finishing one line
            {
                out_f << endl;
                // print how many strings there of each type in the current line
                cout << counter[0] << " " << counter[1] << " "
                     << counter[2] << endl;

                // re-initial the counters for the next line!
                for(int i=0;i<CNTR_LEN;i++)
                {
                    counter[i]=0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for instance:

input:

> unknown human species living just 11500 years ago are identified in southern China,
>   which discovered in 15/03/12 or the 3rd of last month

output:

> aaaaaaa aaaaa aaaaaaa aaaaaa aaaa 00000 aaaaa aaa aaa aaaaaaaaaa aa aaaaaaaa xxxxxx
>   aaaaa aaaaaaaaaa aa xxxxxxxx aa aaa xxx aa aaaa aaaaa

Comment: Have you tried to append the string with a `\n` before you write it to the file to get a newline or written a `\n` after every written string?

Comment: shouldn't do that i don't need every string(word or number or anything) in a separated line! i want them in lines as a paragraph for instance !

Comment: Well you'll have to limit the line size somehow. You could count how long each line is and when it reaches a certain point add a `\n` character.

Comment: i may want to to read unlimited line !! but i would limit the string length to 100 each, not the line! I'm putting an example of the input and the output !! in a moments

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. You're testing for eof incorrectly. You have to read first, and then test for eof. You're testing first, then reading.
2. I'm not sure why you're storing the input and output strings. All you need is a count of how many characters were in the token, and a couple of booleans to keep track of white kind of token it is.

This seems like homework, so I'm not going to produce a working solution, but it should look something like

```
char ch;
int ch_cnt = 0;
while (inp_f.get(ch)) {
  ++ch_cnt;
  if (isspace(ch)) {
    // update the count for the right type of token
    // output the symbols to replace the token
    // clear all the type flags
    // then output ch (to get a space) and set ch_cnt back to 0
  } else if (isdigit(ch)) {
    // it's either a number or mixed
  } else if (isalpha(ch)) {
    // it's either a word or mixed
  } else {
    // it's mixed
  }

  if ('\n' == ch) {
    // output the counts of the token types
    // set the counts back to 0
  }
}
```

Comment: First of all, indeed it is a homework and thanks for replying and the idea, now about the second thing "why i'm storing the string" because it's been asked to not copy the same string continuously if there are such in the input (if there are two words or more are the same after each other exactly not to decode&copy them all ,just one !)